# 'module.exports' not working with gRPC (npm-project)

Tags: javascript, npm, grpc, protoc

I create protobuf files and grpc services with this command:

```
protoc -I=./src/proto $(find ./src/proto -iname *.proto) --js_out=import_style=commonjs:./src/grpc-generated --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:./src/grpc-generated
```

JS-files are generated and at the end of each there is an export.

```
module.exports = proto.tech.lmru.auth.grpc.service.generated.impl;
```

I import like this:

```
const userServiceClient = require('../grpc-generated/AuthEntity_grpc_web_pb.js');
```

But browser catch exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '# <Object>'
```

---

### What to do?

Comment: This will help be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449999/webpack-import-module-exports-in-the-same-module-caused-error

Comment: Cannot edit generated code