# Razzle, IE11 and HappiJS bundling

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, microsoft-edge, razzle

I've got a server-side rendered react app which uses Razzle. I'm importing @hapi/joi since that's what I want to use for my validation both server and client side.  IE11 and Edge 18 are supported browsers for my app and I've got to be able to run my app(client-side) on them.

@hapi/joi v16 is not compiled(shipped as ES6) by default which leads me to think that I have to manually compile the dependency in my project due to the support required for Edge 18 and IE11.

I am attempting to do so wit this config:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  modifyBabelOptions() {
    return {
      presets: ['razzle/babel'],
    };
  },
  modify(config, { target, dev }, webpack) {
    // package un-transpiled packages
    const babelRuleIndex = config.module.rules.findIndex(
      (rule) => rule.use && rule.use[0].loader && rule.use[0].loader.includes('babel-loader')
    );
    config.module.rules[babelRuleIndex] = Object.assign(config.module.rules[babelRuleIndex], {
      include: [
        ...config.module.rules[babelRuleIndex].include,
        fs.realpathSync('./node_modules/@hapi/')
      ],
    });
    config.externals =
      target === 'node'
        ? [
            nodeExternals({
              whitelist: [
                dev ? 'webpack/hot/poll?300' : null,
                /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|otf)$/,
                /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
                /\.(mp4|mp3|ogg|swf|webp)$/,
                /\.(css|scss|sass|sss|less)$/,
                /^@hapi/,
              ].filter(Boolean),
            }),
          ]
        : [];
    // return
    return config;
  },
};
```

However I seem to be getting a `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object` when I try to run my project.
I know that the error is around import and module.exports but I'm not quite seeing where I am going wrong here since I  `require` Joi in my app.

What am I doing wrong here?

PS:
Pushed this up to a repo for anyone interested in case you want to have a look and the config isn't enough context
https://github.com/AntonioValerievVasilev/razzle--hapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs when mixing the CommonJS `module.exports` with ES Modules. I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039) in GitHub. You could try [the solution](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-273890888) mentioned in it: replacing all `module.exports = ...` to `export default ...`.

Besides, if you use `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`, it will change `require` to `import` where it isn't supposed to. It can be solved to add `"sourceType": "unambiguous"` in `.babelrc` or config.js. You could refer to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449999/webpack-import-module-exports-in-the-same-module-caused-error/56283408#56283408) in this thread:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ...
  ],

  "sourceType": "unambiguous"
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it was the  "sourceType": "unambiguous" which resolved it for me!