# How do I fix 'Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>' when adding a 2nd function to module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I've unfortunately been stuck for about 5 days now on this. I've Googled and nothing has worked for me.
I have a utils.js file with a bunch of stuff to help me out. When I add the function "doesUserContainRoles" to the exports, my Chrome Console gives me the error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

When I remove the function, everything in the utils file works perfectly with 0 issues at all. It's just as soon as I add the function, I get this error. I am requiring the utils file by the following:

```js
const utils = require("../../../utils");
```

And there are no `import`s used with this. (I know that `module.exports` and `import` don't work together)

What I am using:

- Vue.js @vue/cli 4.5.8
- Node.js v15.2.0

#### Files:

`utils.js`

```js
const winston = require("winston");
const { datadog } = require("./credentials.js");
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const base_url = "http://localhost:3001/api/v1"

// Winston ~
const httpTransportOptions = {
  host: datadog.logger.host,
  path: datadog.logger.path,
  ssl: datadog.logger.ssl
};
const customLevels = {
  levels: {
    emergency: 0,
    alert: 1,
    critical: 2,
    error: 3,
    warn: 4,
    notice: 5,
    info: 6,
    debug: 7,
    success: 8
  },
}
const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  levels: customLevels.levels,
  exitOnError: false,
  format: format.json(),
  transports: [
    new transports.Http(httpTransportOptions),
  ],
});

const commonMessages = {
  accessPage: "User Accessed a Page",
  restrictedPage: "Attempt at accessing restricted page"
}

function alertGeneral() {
  alert("Oops! An error has occurred. Please try again later. If this problem continues, please contact Vinniehat.");
}
function doesUserContainRoles(userRoles, containsRoles) {
  return !!userRoles.some(role => containsRoles.includes(role));
}

module.exports = {
  logger,
  commonMessages,
  base_url,
  alertGeneral,
  doesUserContainRoles
}
```

Here is the error stack:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at Module.eval (utils.js?1b23:45)
    at eval (utils.js:68)
    at Module../utils.js (app.js:1944)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (router.js?9883:19)
    at Module../src/router/router.js (app.js:1812)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (main.js:34)
```

I have tried to use `export default` also. When doing this, my frontend works. The website loads with no errors. My backend though, which is ran using Express.js, then throws an error:

```
Unhandled rejection E:\Development\Websites\iceberg-gaming-website\utils.js:45
export default {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1018:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1066:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Development\Websites\iceberg-gaming-website\express\modules\user.js:9:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at E:\Development\Websites\iceberg-gaming-website\express\express.js:27:27
    at tryCatcher (E:\Development\Websites\iceberg-gaming-website\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
```

Comment: Let start simple. Change to - const doesUserContainRoles = (userRoles, containsRoles) => !!userRoles.some(role => containsRoles.includes(role)) beside that add the full stack trace

Comment: @MichaelHobbs Ok! I've changed that on over and added the stack trace to the original post.

Comment: are you running webpack on your server code? I also see eval on main.js I have a feeling a lot it going on here. You should push this to github and provide a link. You are doing something very strange to be getting this error.

Comment: The utils file is being required in an express file if that is what you mean. Also the repository is unfortunately private. I would be happy to provide any files that you need though. Sorry about that!

Comment: Since it’s an error thrown by webpack: have you tried using ES6 module `export` instead?

Comment: I have tried using ```export default {}``` before, in which my website loads, I don't get an error on Chrome, but my backend(run with Express, then errors out). I am updating the original post to include the error stack if I were to change to export default. Edit: The same error does occur without ```default```

Comment: Are you trying to include this utils file both in the frontend project and in the backend project?

Comment: Correct. The utils is being used on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in `main.js > router.js > utils.js` you are mixing CommonJSModules and ESModules. Something along the lines of `CommonJSModule --requires--> ESModule --requires--> AnotherCommonJSModule`

Edit: This seems to be relevant as well `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449999/webpack-import-module-exports-in-the-same-module-caused-error`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@quasar/babel-preset-app'
  ],

  "sourceType": "unambiguous"
}
```

Comment: It works! Awesome thank you so much. The only thing I had to change was the preset, which was ```@vue/app```