# How to export Javascript class which can be shared by NodeJS and ES6?

Tags: node.js, electron, commonjs, es6-class

I have an Electron app integrated with Flask server. The app has both HTML loaded by Flask server (flask-page.html ES6) and Electron renderer (render-page.html NodeJS).

I want to share a class defined in a file for Flask and Renderer to avoid duplicated code, as class is exactly the same, but with different export/import.

Now, it's defined in 2 files as followings:

sharedclass-nodejs.js

```
    class sharedClass {
      sameMethod() {

      }
    }

    module.exports = {sharedClass}
```

sharedclass-es6.js

```
    export class sharedClass {
      sameMethod() {

      }
    }
```

load-flask.js

```
    import {sharedClass} from "sharedclass-es6.js"
```

flask-page.html  (Flask server)

```
    <script type="module" src="sharedclass-es6.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="load-flask.js"></script>
```

load-render.js

```
    const {sharedClass} = require("sharedclass-nodejs.js")
```

render-page.html (Electron render UI)

```
    <script src="sharedclass-nodejs.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to define 1 copy of "class sharedClass" in 1 file, such as NodeJS style export, and use it in ES6?

Comment: You can import something exported with `module.exports` just the same way you do with something exported with `export`

Comment: The import does not work in ES6 js if exported as module.exports, which is commonJS style (NodeJS).

Comment: I do it on my app, and it works fine with the correct babel configuration.

Comment: Babel configuration is what I am looking for. Can you give some details? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Node.js CommonJS modules in ES6 import/export modules using babel or webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472430/how-can-i-use-node-js-commonjs-modules-in-es6-import-export-modules-using-babel)